# Как устанавливать и импортировать библиотеки в C++ в Visual Studio Code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, library

Всё либо просто не работает либо выводит ошибку по типу:

```
main.cpp:2:17: fatal error: SDL.h: No such file or directory
#include "SDL.h"
                ^
compilation terminated.
```

Comment: Откуда вы ставили GCC? Из MSYS2 или нет?

Comment: у меня стоит g++, gcc не устанавливал

Comment: Я начинающий так что пока мало что понимаю

Comment: Команды `gcc` (**G**NU **C** **c**ompiler) и `g++` - это все части GCC (**G**NU **c**ompiler **c**ollection). Еще раз тот же вопрос, у вас стоит MSYS2 или нет?

Comment: стоит но не работет почему то

Comment: Напишите точно, как вы его ставили, какие команды там запускали, откуда взяли SDL2, и т.п.

Comment: g++ из mingw которую я пытался установить с помощю MSYS2 но не получилось. Запускал команды от сюда https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30069830/how-can-i-install-mingw-w64-and-msys2

Comment: потом установил mingw от сюда https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/

Comment: SDL скачивал тут https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/releases/tag/release-2.26.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сносите к чертям все свои установленные GCC, MinGW, MSYS2, SDL2 и т.п.

Заново ставите [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/).

Открываете его консоль. Там несколько ярлыков, выбираете со словом UCRT64 в названии.

В консоли должно быть фиолетовыми буквами написано `UCRT64` (не `MSYS`). Если там не тот текст, то значит ошиблись ярлыком.

Обновляетесь командой `pacman -Syuu`. В какой-то момент консоль может закрыться - тогда нужно перезапустить и повторить ту же команду заново, это нормально.

Ставите компилятор, SDL2, и еще всякие полезные штуки: `pacman -S mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-gcc mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-gdb mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-pkgconf mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-SDL2`.

Запускаете команду `pkg-config --libs --cflags sdl2`, чтобы узнать правильные флаги компилятора для SDL2.

Пробуете скомпилировать вашу прогармму с этими флагами: `g++ my_program.cpp флаги_из_pkgconfig`.

Если все успешно, добавляете в PATH путь `C:\msys64\ucrt64\bin` (туда ставится `g++.exe`), и копируете те же самые флаги в VSC.

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144671/discussion-on-answer-by-holyblackcat-----); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.